# C source inclusion name length

Tags: c, gcc, clang

According to the C Standard, subclause 6.10.2, paragraph 5 [ISO/IEC 9899:2011],

> The implementation shall provide unique mappings for sequences
>   consisting of one or more nondigits or digits (6.4.2.1) followed by a
>   period (.) and a single nondigit. The first character shall not be a
>   digit. The implementation may ignore distinctions of alphabetical case
>   and restrict the mapping to eight significant characters before the
>   period.

This would mean that if two include files have first 8 characters in common, the header it actually picks is undefined.

When I compile using clang or gcc, I haven't really faced this issue. However, is there a documented behavior for source file inclusion in GCC and Clang?

In the modern world, I would find it weird if any compiler really restricts to 8 characters.

Reference: [C11 WG14 draft version N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), [Cert C Coding standard](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/PRE08-C.+Guarantee+that+header+file+names+are+unique)

Comment: POSIX has `NAME_MAX` and `PATH_MAX` macros, _gcc_ may be based on these limits as well. For the 8 characters limit, maybe in the embedded world?

Comment: The key word is _may_. Maybe the problem can be triggered in system with old fat with [8.3 filename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) format

Comment: @md5 Even if an embedded system can be limited, usually the firmware is developed using a cross-compiler on a modern system.

Comment: @md5 Those are maximum length limits, not the 'distinction' limit.

Comment: I am more curious as to whether there is a documented behavior for the 'distinction limit' in these compilers. In the case of  8.3 filename, would it not be that I can't even have the file with such a name? Though the question is actually more generic, I am actually trying to evaluate if this will bite me as long as I am using one of these compilers on a Linux platform. The remaining part is more for curiosity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This would mean that if two include files have first 8 characters in common, the header it actually picks is undefined.

No, I'd argue against that: Looking at the exact wording we see that standard uses:

> [..] The implementation **may** ignore [..]

It's "may", not "*shall*". If the later was used it would indeed mean that the behavior was undefined (N1570 $4/2). Since "may" is used as-is, without exact declaration I think it's safe to assume the normal meaning of the word ([source](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/may?s=t), emphasis mine):

> used to express opportunity or **permission**

Thus, an implementation is allowed to only consider the first 8 characters, but it doesn't have to.

Funny thing: I cannot find an exact documentation for the "distinction limit" of the "sequence" in GCC's manual, meaning (N1570 $4/8, emphasis mine) ...

> An implementation **shall** be accompanied by a document that defines **all** implementation defined and locale-specific characteristics and all extensions.

... that GCC could (under some very pedantic point of view) be considered a nonconforming implementation. The practical relevant part of their manual, as @PaulGriffiths pointed out, is probably ([source](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation-limits.html#Implementation-limits), point 4 in the list):

> Significant initial characters in an identifier or macro name.
>
> The preprocessor treats all characters as significant. The C standard requires only that the first 63 be significant.

Regarding the comment:

> [..] I am actually trying to evaluate if this will bite me as long as I am using one of these compilers on a Linux platform. [..]

I really doubt that this will ever (again?) be an issue.

Comment: See point 4 here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation-limits.html#Implementation-limits for something close to it, at least.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Thank you, though if we're nitpicking the "thing" that's constrained here is neither an identifier nor a macro name, but a "sequence"

Comment: True, although I don't see this point listed as implementation-defined behavior requiring documentation in Annex J anyway, so it's probably not a conformance issue.